# deploying contract with mainnet-fork then also ganache is running

Tags: solidity

Hey i m following patrick collins solidity course.
I m currently on lesson 6 : Brownie fundMe
In that course he taught us to use mainnet-fork but when i m deploying contract using mainnet-fork network from .yaml file then also ganache is running

Comment: With the information you provided there is no way a contributor can know whats going on, please include the contract code, the command you are trying to run, and the error message. Also unless the course is public this is a question you should ask them

Comment: If I'm not wrong ganache runs the fork, but make sure that ganache isn't running before launching the mainnet fork.